# When to use *To + Verb*

Tags: sentence-construction

When to use *to* before Verb? Please explain considering my below examples.

Example 1

a) They made the child drink the milk.

b) They make the child to drink the milk.

Example 2

a) He asked her to marry him

b) He asked her marry him

Example 3

a) She makes her children learn their lessons everyday

b) She makes her children to learn their lessons everyday

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't actually have to do with "to" **before** a verb, but with "to" **after** a verb.

A verb like "ask" will take "to" or "for" after it, while "make" usually doesn't (an exception is when it's used in the passive voice).

Consider these correct examples to see how the verb after the "to" doesn't have an impact:

- They made her drink the milk.
- They made her marry him.
- He asked her to drink the milk.
- He asked her to marry him.

Communication/command verbs (some examples: "ask," "tell," "order") often take infinitives.